# how to delay ajax response - asp.net mvc using partialview

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

My drop down list data are being passed to the controller using ajax helper in the view and in the controller, the partial view is returned using those data. When I run the application to see the partial view, it throws an error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

However, when I debug it slowly, partial view is correctly shown in the page.
I assume that since the partial view is correctly shown as I intended in debug mode, I probably need to delay the response for ajax? Is this the right approach? Any ideas?

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEmployee", "Employee", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",    
    UpdateTargetId = "showResult"
})) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">   
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CountryId">Country</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", null, "-- Select Country --", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "FillCity()" })                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="City">City</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "CityId", "CityName"), "-- Select City --", new { @class = "form-control" })              
            </div>
        </div>       

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div id="showResult"></div>

@section Scripts {    
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function FillCity() {
            var countryId = $('#CountryId').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Posting/FillCity',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { country: countryId },
                success: function (cities) {
                    $("#City").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                    $("#City").append($('<option>-- Select City --</option>'))
                    $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
                        $("#City").append($('<option></option>').val(city.CityId).html(city.CityName));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetEmployee(int CountryId, int city)
{
    var model = db.Employees
        .Where(x => x.Country.CountryId == CountryId && x.City.CityId == city);
    return PartialView("PartialEmployee", model);
}
```

PartialView:

```
@model IEnumerable<PokeGoTradeModel.Models.Employee>

<table class="table">
    <tr>        
        <th>Country</th>       
        <th>City</th>        
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>         
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.CountryName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City.CityName)</td> 
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is my inner exception stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Comment: No, that would not be the issue. What are the inner exception details?

Comment: Horrible approach to delay ajax. Are you sure when you debugging, you are sending the same values through to your controller?

Comment: @StephenMuecke so the inner exception says "{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}"

Comment: So that's the problem :). But you have not shown the relevant code or indicated which line throws that exception.

Comment: @monstertjie_za yeah they are sending the same values. BTW, you wouldn't believe it because when I am in debugging mode and press f11 quickly in the partial view where I set break point for foreach loop, it throws that error, but if I wait for a few seconds and press f11 slowly, the values are correctly going in and as a result it properly renders in the view.

Comment: when I set a breakpoint in PartialView for @foreach (var item in Model), and press f11 quickly, throws that error, but if I Step Into slowly, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was all because of lazy-loading. So my employee model has navigation properties of Country and City. In my Actionresult GetEmployee method, I needed to add more lines that includes navigation properties for employee model. So for example,

```
var model = db.employees.Include(x=>x.Country)
                        .Include(x=>x.City)
                        .Where(x=>x.Country.CountryId=countryId && x.City.CityId=cityId);
```

Hope it can help others if you have similar issues when using ajax for partial view. If you used virtual property in your model, for example:

```
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
```

make sure you use ***Include*** in your query.